# How to check whether another app is minimized or not?

Tags: c#

How can I check whether another application is minimized or not?  For instance in a loop like this:

```
foreach(Process p in processes)
{
  // Does a process have a window?
  // If so, is it minimized, normal, or maximized
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

    private struct WINDOWPLACEMENT {
        public int length;
        public int flags;
        public int showCmd;
        public System.Drawing.Point ptMinPosition;
        public System.Drawing.Point ptMaxPosition;
        public System.Drawing.Rectangle rcNormalPosition;
    }

if (p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero) {
    if (p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Notepad")) {
        WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
        GetWindowPlacement(p.MainWindowHandle, ref placement);
        switch (placement.showCmd) {
           case 1:
             Console.WriteLine("Normal");
             break;
           case 2:
             Console.WriteLine("Minimized");
             break;
           case 3:
             Console.WriteLine("Maximized");
             break;
        }
    }                   
}
```

Comment: Be careful if you plan to use the rcNormalPosition property -- the values for Right, and Bottom are being stored into Width and Height instead, which could make your windows seem deceptively large.

Answer (score 7):

There is no such thing as a minimized "application."  The best alternative would be to check whether the application's Main Window is Iconic (minimized).

[IsIconic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633527(VS.85).aspx) can be used to check for the iconic state of a window.  It will return 1 if a window is minimized.  You can call this with [process.MainWindowHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle.aspx).

Comment: To find out whether a window is maximized you can call IsZoomed.

Answer (score 6):

you can use isZoomed for maximized and isIconic for minimized by injecting user32 dll

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool IsZoomed(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Answer (score 4):

If a window is minimized (in Windows Forms at least) both Location.X and Location.Y values are -32000

Comment: +1: This might not be a perfectly "clean" solution but it certainly does the trick. But you should be aware that window positions can be negative even if they are not minimized e.g. when a window is lapping out the monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of enumerating Processes, you should use the native [EnumWindows() function](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumWindows.html) and then call IsIconic.

Comment: Why? Btw, EnumWindows was my original version, but I changed it to managed code.

Comment: @AngryHacker: You can still P/Invoke into EnumWindows.  That's potentially better than trying to use process, unless you're only interested in the main window.  You still need P/Invoke for IsIconic (or GetWindowPlacement).

Comment: I don't think it matters... I didn't know you could say p.MainWindowHandle, and it was an easy way to get the handles.  Whatever works for you.